# focusing input in material ui textfield requires delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am not able to get the `inputRef.current.focus()` to fire without using `setTimeout`.
This seems like a bug, but I'm not sure if it is in React or MaterialUI.

See a demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-gareth-lkmq3?file=/src/App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const [value, setValue] = useState("but focus only works after a timeout");
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  const onChange = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    },
    [setValue]
  );

  const onClickIcon = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("onClickIcon");
    setDisabled(false);

    // this does nothing
    inputRef.current.focus();

    // eventually you'll see the input gain focus
    setTimeout(() => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }, 2000);
  }, [inputRef]);

  const onFocus = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("onFocus");
  }, []);

  const onBlur = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("onBlur");
    setDisabled(true);
  }, [setDisabled]);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
      <Box my={4}>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
          ISSUE: Button click does not immediately focus input
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Grid container direction="row" wrap="nowrap">
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          disabled={disabled}
          label="input should become focused when LOCK is clicked"
          inputRef={inputRef}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          onFocus={onFocus}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          color="primary"
        />
        <IconButton onClick={onClickIcon} color="primary">
          <LockIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>
      <Box my={4}>
        <ProTip />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "create-react-app",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "clsx": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-scripts": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: A disabled input can't receive receive focus. `setDisabled(false)` happens asynchronously since it is a state change. The `setTimeout` causes the `inputRef.current.focus()` call to occur after the input has been enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rerender the lifecycle in order to enable the auto focus since its async. Here is my solution, check this out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-ellis-qnkn6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I dont want auto focus. I want focus only when a button is clicked.

Comment: I like your solution, but your description completely confused me. I don't see any async, but I do see that you used state to trigger `useEffect`. I think this works, so I'll accept the answer. Thank you! but I wish you would consider a different description and show your code in the answer.